# Why are CloudWatch Logs sent from my Windows EC2 Instance not showing up on AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have set up CloudWatch Logs on ec2 windows server-R2 but it doesn't show up on the AWS console. (My IAM user has FullAccess)
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/using-cloudwatch-logs-with-amazon-ec2-running-microsoft-windows-server/

My CloudWatch json file looks like below:

```
{
  "EngineConfiguration": {
    "PollInterval": "00:00:15",
    "Components": [
      {
        "Id": "ApplicationEventLog",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
          "LogName": "Application",
          "Levels": "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "SystemEventLog",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
          "LogName": "System",
          "Levels": "7"
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "SecurityEventLog",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
          "LogName": "Security",
          "Levels": "7"
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "ETW",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.EventLog.EventLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
          "LogName": "Microsoft-Windows-WinINet/Analytic",
          "Levels": "7"
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "IISLogs",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
          "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\inetpub\\logs\\LogFiles\\W3SVC1",
          "TimestampFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
          "Encoding": "UTF-8",
          "Filter": "",
          "CultureName": "en-US",
          "TimeZoneKind": "UTC",
          "LineCount": "3"
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "CustomLogs",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CustomLog.CustomLogInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
          "LogDirectoryPath": "C:\\CustomLogs\\",
          "TimestampFormat": "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
          "Encoding": "UTF-8",
          "Filter": "",
          "CultureName": "en-US",
          "TimeZoneKind": "Local"
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "PerformanceCounter",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
          "CategoryName": "Memory",
          "CounterName": "Available MBytes",
          "InstanceName": "",
          "MetricName": "Memory",
          "Unit": "Megabytes",
          "DimensionName": "",
          "DimensionValue": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "CloudWatchLogs",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatchLogsOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
          "AccessKey": "accesskey",
          "SecretKey": "secretkey",
          "Region": "eu-west-1",
          "LogGroup": "Default-Log-Group",
          "LogStream": "{instance_id}"
        }
      },
      {
        "Id": "CloudWatch",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatch.CloudWatchOutputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
          "AccessKey": "accesskey",
          "SecretKey": "secretkey",
          "Region": "eu-west-1",
          "NameSpace": "Windows/Default"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Flows": {
      "Flows": [
        "(ApplicationEventLog,SystemEventLog),CloudWatchLogs",
        "PerformanceCounter,CloudWatch"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As I found it also needs to install SSM to show it up on the AWS console?! I am doing the installation process of SSM based on this link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/managed-instances.html#install-managed-win

But it can't download the file, the details are as followed:

```
PS C:\Program Files (x86)\AWS Tools\PowerShell\AWSPowerShell> $dir = $env:TEMP + "\ssm"
> New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $dir
> cd $dir
> $username = admin
> $password = 1234
> $wc = New-Object System.Net.Networkcredential($username, $password)
> $wc.DownloadFile("https://amazon-ssm-region.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/windows_amd64/AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe", $dir + "\AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe")



You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

At line:1 char:1

+ $wc.DownloadFile("https://amazon-ssm-    region.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/windows_amd64 ...

+ 

  + CategoryInfo  : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException

  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Is there any idea what the problem is?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to send to CloudWatch logs?  Just Windows event logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:** If you're coming here from a search engine and are looking for help with EC2Launch/EC2Config 4.x on Windows Server 2016, see this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/windows-ami-version-history.html#win2k16-amis) for related changes.  This guide was written with the EC2Config 3.x Windows Service on older Windows Servers in mind, and advice given may not directly parallel EC2Launch.

Take note of your version of EC2Config and see the following documentation for further version-specific advice:

- [Use EC2Config 3.x or Earlier to Configure CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/send_logs_to_cwl_instances.html#ec2config-3x)
- [Use EC2Config 4.x to Configure CloudWatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/send_logs_to_cwl_instances.html#ec2config-4x)

For users migrating from 3.x to 4.x: you'll specifically need to:

- Add `"IsEnabled":true` to your `AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.json` JSON file.
- Move this file from `C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings\` to `C:\Program Files\Amazon\SSM\Plugins\awsCloudWatch\`

---

You're asking a lot for a single question, so I'm going to answer this in parts:

**1) The guide you're following is not for your use case**

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/managed-instances.html#install-managed-win) you linked to is for setting up an SSM agent in a hybrid environment, as in an environment with both EC2 instances and on-premise machines working together. Since you're working on an EC2 instance instead of an on-premise machine, this document isn't relevant to you. This changes the following assumptions:

- You should download EC2Config instead of the SSM Agent explicitly. (see step 3)
- You need an [IAM Instance Profile](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) attached to your instance instead of an IAM User with all relevant permissions. (see step 4)

**2) Verify your SSM agent with [EC2 Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/)**

You may already have the SSM Agent installed, per the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/remote-commands-prereq.html):

> SSM Agent is installed by default on Windows Server 2016 instances and instances created from Windows Server 2003-2012 R2 AMIs published in November 2016 or later.

To check in the AWS Web Console, nagivate to `EC2 > Commands > Command History > Run A Command`.

[image]

In the 'Run A Command' UI look for a button 'Select Instances'. This will open a dropdown of running instances that are running an SSM Agent.

[image]

If your instance is listed here, congratulations! You already have an SSM agent installed. Skip step 3.

**3) Setting up an SSM agent for CloudWatch Logs**

You should [install the latest version of EC2Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_Install.html). The SSM Agent comes bundled with EC2Config and is installed alongside. You can do this interactively, or with PowerShell (this example requires v5):

```
iwr https://ec2-downloads-windows.s3.amazonaws.com/EC2Config/EC2Install.zip -UseBasicParsing -OutFile Ec2Config.zip
Expand-Archive Ec2Config.zip
.\Ec2Config\Ec2Install.exe /install
```

After installation, the EC2 Config Service will be restarted.  Go ahead and restart the instance as well (if you're [managing your password with EC2Config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-passwords.html) you may not be able to retrieve it from the console after reboot if you haven't re-enabled that setting -- copy it somewhere just in case!), and then follow step 2 again to verify that your instance is available for EC2 Run Command.  Added perk: from now on, you'll be able to update EC2Config and SSM Agent from EC2 Run Command.

**4) Verify that your IAM Instance Profile's IAM Role has sufficient permissions**

AWS Documentation covers this [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/send_logs_to_cwl.html#iam_permissions), so I won't retread that.

If no instance profile is currently attached to your EC2 instance, you should [create an AMI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_EBSbacked_WinAMI.html) and launch a new instance with all of the same configuration as your current one, except that it uses the new AMI you created and uses an IAM Role with sufficient permissions.

**5) You don't need to explicitly specify your AWS Credentials in the CloudWatch Config**

AccessKey and SecretKey should be left blank, because the credentials will instead inherited from your IAM instance profile:

```
{
    "Id": "CloudWatchLogs",
    "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatchLogsOutput,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
    "Parameters": {
        "AccessKey": "",
        "SecretKey": "",
        "Region": "eu-west-1",
        "LogGroup": "MyLogGroup",
        "LogStream": "{instance_id}"
    }
},
{
    "Id": "CloudWatch",
    "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatch.CloudWatchOutputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
    "Parameters": 
    {
        "AccessKey": "",
        "SecretKey": "",
        "Region": "eu-west-1",
        "NameSpace": "MyMetricsNameSpace"
    }
}
```

After you make any changes to your config file, restart EC2Config (or your instance itself if that is easier in your workflow) and the changes should be applied.

**6) Troubleshooting**

Logs related to sending local logs to CW can be found on your instance here: `C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Logs\Ec2ConfigLog.txt`. This was invaluable to me the first time I configured this.

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/send_logs_to_cwl.html#Troubleshooting_CloudWatchLogs) also has guidance for common problems.

---

Aside from that, everything looks ok to me.  Maybe handle the problem in smaller pieces -- tackling setting up Windows Events Logs first, then metrics, then custom logs.

Comment: Perfect guidance :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I got many problems with Cloudwatch metrics, but i finally figured out most of them.

In order to receive metrics you will need to add `"IsEnabled":true` at the top of the file like so:

```
{
    "IsEnabled": true
    "EngineConfiguration": {
        "PollInterval": "00:00:15",
        "Components": [
```

Also you have to update the EC2Config to the latest version from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/UsingConfig_Install.html)